# ExtJS/Sencha Touch 2 - How to grab an element/component with multiple classes in

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm not sure if I'm going crazy. I've tested this on Kitchen sink also so it's not just me.

I've tried:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('container[cls="blah"]');
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('container[cls~="blah"]');
```

But after it has a second class, it seems you can't get ahold of something by a class that it has.

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

If you go to http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/e.../#demo/buttons

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button')[0];
// returns element
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button')[0].addCls('meep');
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[cls="meep"')[0];
// returns element
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button')[0].addCls('blah');
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[cls="meep"')[0];
// returns undefined
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[cls~="meep"')[0];
// returns undefined
```

Comment: In ExtJS button instances don't keep the `cls` property at all (though they have the config) so none of the working Sencha Touch examples would work. Try inspecting your button in the DOM after you add a cls and see how it is getting attached.

Answer (score 2):

Because of what I expect and how the documentation words their DomQuery I think the above should work but is bugged.

I got around this by creating a new xtype and using that instead in ComponentQuery like so:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Deposit', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container'
});

Ext.ComponentQuery('meep');
```

I guess I was trying to go about it like you would in jQuery, add a class and retrieve it using that, but with the Component stuff it's confusing.

I think this SHOULD have worked but it does not (tested in 2.0.1.1, 2.1.0b3):

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[cls*="meep"')[0];
```

Comment: wonder if this is fixed in 2.2.1 I'm using 2.1.1 and have the same issue. your xtype trick would work well thanks